# How do i ask the user to input how far away someone is?

Tags: python

How do I ask the user to input how far away someone is?

e.g.

```
"How far away is the closest person: "
```

and then get it to tell me if it is under 600m

e.g.

```
"Canon start Rocket Lift Off because the closest person is less than 600m away
```

Comment: Did you try anything? Please [edit] your question and include the code you have tried.

Comment: Not a dupe of that question (related possibly). This question asks how to do input. The linked question asks how to use a specific function you *already know* the name of - and is python 2 specific.

Answer (score 2):

Use Python's [`input()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#input) method.

```
>>> a = input("Input the distance: ")
Input the distance: 800
>>> print(a)
800
```

For the 600m requirement, read up on [`if` statements](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements).

```
>>> a = "test"
>>> if a == "test":
...     print("true")
...
true
```

Answer (score 1):

To ask the user a question, do:

```
x = raw_input("How far away is the closest person: ")
```

for python 2.7 or

```
x = input("How far away is the closest person: ")
```

for python 3

and then as you will probably have worked out by now:

```
if x < 600:
    # do something
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `print()` to display information, `input()` to receive the input info, and `if` statement to determine whether the distance is enough. `float(input())` means converting what you input to a float type object.

```
print "How far away is the closest person: "
if float(input()) <= 600:
    print "Canon start Rocket Lift Off because the closest person is less than 600m away"
```